# SAML authentication on client side with angular 2/4

Tags: node.js, angular, express, saml

In angular2/4 can we maintain http browser session throw with IDP. In my project i work SAML authentication client side. I am using angular 4. It is possible with nodeJs but i do not get anything with angular